YAML: bad indentation of a mapping entry
I'm getting this error "bad indentation of a mapping entry", on the "repo_name" line and I can't fix it. Does anybody know why?
  - name: Trigger Workflow en repositorio de prueba
    uses: actions/create-repository-dispatch@v1
    with:
      repository: XXXXXXX
      event_type: trigger_test
      client_payload: ${{ toJson({
        repo_name: ${{ github.repository }},
        knwf_url: ${{ steps.upload_knwf.outputs.artifact_url }}
      }) }}

The workflow fails on this part.

Please add the link to actions/create-repository-dispatch@v1 in your question. Apparently, looks like that client_payload should be a multiline string. That action's docs might have it.

At a YAML level if you want that to be a multiline string, see e.g. https://yaml-multiline.info/. But also inside ${{ }} you have to put a valid expression, and that doesn't include additional ${{ }}.

actions/create-repository-dispatch doesn't seem to exist. However, the config is similar to https://github.com/peter-evans/repository-dispatch. See https://github.com/peter-evans/repository-dispatch?tab=readme-ov-file#client-payload for details on payload.

The easiest way to submit JSON input to an action is to use a literal block scalar:
- name: Trigger Workflow en repositorio de prueba
    uses: actions/create-repository-dispatch@v1
    with:
      repository: XXXXXXX
      event_type: trigger_test
      client_payload: |
        {
          "repo_name": "${{ github.repository }}",
          "knwf_url": "${{ steps.upload_knwf.outputs.artifact_url }}"
        }


The error is likely due to the way the client_payload is defined.
YAML is very sensitive to indentation, and it’s crucial to ensure that the indentation levels are correct. You can try this
- name: Trigger Workflow en repositorio de prueba
  uses: actions/create-repository-dispatch@v1
  with:
    repository: XXXXXXX
    event_type: trigger_test
    client_payload: >
      ${{ toJson({
        "repo_name": "${{ github.repository }}",
        "knwf_url": "${{ steps.upload_knwf.outputs.artifact_url }}"
      }) }}```


Thank you very much for supporting me. I tried your suggestion, however, it´s still sending me an error "The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/test.yml (Line: 26, Col: 27): Unexpected symbol: '{'. Located at position 8 within expression: toJson({
"repo_name": "${{ github.repository" .
